# Launching app over SSH with DISPLAY when user not logged in

Tags: ssh, display

After searching and searching without any luck I'm hoping someone here can enlighten me.

I have a PC (Ubuntu with encrypted home dir). I wake this PC up from a shell script on my phone, the PC shows the login screen.

I do not physically log in to the PC.

I run another shell script on my phone where:

- I connect through SSH
- decrypt my user's home dir
- `export DISPLAY=:0.0`
- launch app

the script completes and exits.

The app is successfully launched because when I manually log in on the PC in the morning and do a `ps -ef` it shows the process.The thing is however I can't see the GUI. I have to kill the process and start the app again.

I think it has something to do with the fact that there is no GUI session when starting the app over SSH so `DISPLAY` doesn't matter.

If I manually log in first and then run a script from my phone which:

- I connect through SSH
- `export DISPLAY=:0.0`
- launch app

the script completes and exits, and I see the GUI of the application showing up on my PC.

Comment: The DISPLAY variable should be set if the SSH session has X enabled. You might be overwriting it and pointing it back to the desktop. If you log in with SSH -X, what does `echo $DISPLAY` show?

Comment: Do you want the app UI to appear on the phone or on the desktop?

Comment: @PeterWestlake it shows localhost:10.0 I didn't know about -X, this looks really useful!

Comment: @Thor this is not what I'm looking for although I just learned it is really useful. I want to start an app on my PC from my phone or laptop over SSH when my PC is not logged in, later when I log in to my PC with the same user I want to be able to access the GUI of the app I started over SSH while the PC was not logged in.

Comment: You should be able to do this with a [vncserver](http://www.tightvnc.com/), it packaged for most GNU/Linux flavors.

Comment: To elaborate on the real issue:  You cannot connect to a display that does not exist!  Because no user is logged in, the only "display" is the login screen itself (which you don't want).  @Thor proposed the only possible workaround, which is to launch a virtual display (or connect to an existing one if possible) using a tool like `vncserver`, which you can connect to from another X session later.